# Dynamic array of an object

Tags: arrays, object, dynamic

Maybe the solution is very simple. It must be, but maybe I am overlooking something

I have:

```
public class Object {
    public int pos_x;
    public int pos_y;
}

Object testObject[] = new object[10]
```

and then somewhere in a function

```
testObject[1].pos_x = 1;
```

It force closes my app.. how? and why? What can be the cause of this.

Furthermore. Ideally I would need something like this

```
testObject[].add_new_object();
testobject[].remove_item(3);
```

can this be done?

Thank you for helping

Comment: Is this Javascript? Platform?

Comment: ... and, arrays are about the least dynamic of any collection ... as a matter of fact, a would say that arrays were never intended to be 'dynamic'.

Comment: Please specify your language.

Answer (score 1):

You have allocated an **array** that can hold 10 objects.

You also need to allocate the objects.

Comment: to explain Steve's answer, after
Object testObject[] = new Object[10]; you have to do (for each i from 0 to 9):
testObject[i] = new Object();

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the language you are using - if C# you cannot use 'Object' as the class name.

First creating a custom object (the 'object' data type):

```
public class MyObject {
    public int pos_x;
    public int pos_y;
}
```

...fair enough, a very basic class that holds coordinates. Next you want to create an array of MyObject. To do that, you declare your array *type* as `MyObject[]` and provide an optional size:

```
MyObject[] myObjArray = new MyObject[10]; // this gives a zero-based array of 10 elements, from 0-9
```

Now, you have the task of filling the array. The most common method would be to use a counter variable that counts from 0 to 9, the same elements we have in our array:

```
for (int i=0; i<=9; i++)
{
    myObjArray[i] = new MyObject();

    // you can also assign the variables' values here
    myObjArray[i].pos_x = GetNextXVal(); // get the X value from somewhere
    myObjArray[i].pos_y = GetNextYVal(); // get the y value from somewhere
}
```

Depending on your language, I'm sure we can point you to some good tutorials, books, or other references to help you get started.

Happy coding!